# How does the keyboard driver binding logic work in UEFI?

Tags: uefi

The EFI console input device can not only have bindings with several keyboard drivers (PS/2, USB, terminal), but also several keyboards can be connected.
For instance: On my portable PC with built-in PS/2 keyboard I connected two USB keyboards by wire, and another wireless USB keyboard.
The keystrokes from all the keyboards enter as if typed from a single keyboard.
On top of that, this works hot plugable.
I assume that every driver binding instance has it's own buffer for scancode and efi code. So which (EDKII) function merges all the keystrokes?
Can I know on what keyboard the key data has been typed?

Answer (score 1):

The merging of console input is done by the UEFI driver named "ConsoleSplitter", which hooks itself between the console drivers and a console user to merge console input and to split console output. I found this description on page 116 of the book "Beyond BIOS, 2° edition" published by intelpress. It is not mentioned on how to know the source of the input data.